# Adapter to VGA, minidisplay or HDMI?

Tags: port

I have a computer with HDMI and mini-display ports, and a monitor with only VGA input, should I get the adapter for the HDMI or the mini-display port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options are equally valid. Both get a digital only signal and both need to actively convert this to the ancient analog format.

I would select either, based on:

1. Price.
2. Future proofing (e.g. do you want to use eyefinity in the future than a third monitor connected via DP is an advantage. Obviously only relevant if you use (or are going to use) an AMD-radeon card).

Comment: In the end I chose the HDMI because it may be compatible with my mini HDMI in the tablet (with the mini HDMI to hdmi cable), which is a big plus. Thank you.